# Visual Studio 2013 and NullReferenceException while trying to run any extensions with SASS

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sass

Some time ago I inherited an Angular app with style sheets made in SCSS. After some research I found out I cannot compile them in Visual studio out-of-the-box and I require some extensions. First I tried out Web Essentials, as this was first thing to come out on Stack Overflow - which turned out to crash my Visual. Short googling after I learned that crashing is frequent, and Web essentials can not compile SASS files anymore anyway, so I checked out some others.

However, after trying out some other solutions - SassyStudio, CompileSASS and Mindscape Web Workbench - I saw that problem which caused crashes in WebEssentials was probably related to my installation of Visual. I tried clearing caches of extensions, uninstalling extensions and reinstalling them back, which didn't help at all.

The extensions seem to crash on opening the file, because when opening visual with no SCSS files open no exceptions are thrown. To check if this was related with this specific file, or something referenced in it, I created empty .SCSS file, which too does not compile.

After checking ActivityLog.xml I saw two errors in it:

```
<entry>
   <record>506</record>
   <time>2015/07/22 12:52:42.951</time>
   <type>Error</type>
   <source>Editor or Editor Extension</source>
   <description>System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Mindscape.VisualSass.Integration.UI.VersionInfoAdornmentFactory.TextViewCreated(IWpfTextView textView)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.WpfTextView.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClassc.&lt;BindContentTypeSpecificAssets&gt;b__9()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.GuardedOperations.CallExtensionPoint(Object errorSource, Action call)
   </description>
</entry>
```

And other one:

```
<entry>
    <record>507</record>
    <time>2015/07/22 12:52:43.113</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Color Theme Service</source>
    <description>The color &apos;Popup&apos; in category &apos;de7b1121-99a4-4708-aedf-15f40c9b332f&apos; does not exist.</description>
</entry>
```

The first one was also thrown in WebEssentials and CompileSASS. I'm running Visual Studio 2013 Premium update 4 on Windows 8.1 professional. SCSS files are probably ok, as they compile normally in Scout and some internet compilers. None of the installed plugins had started, as some of them were supposed to add context menus, and none had shown.

No idea what now. Help?

EDIT: some of the problems, those related to NuGET were caused by a installation of Cordova tools. After deinstalling, problems with context menus were solved. Problems with sass tools are still there.

EDIT2: Upgrading to Upgrade 5 did not solve the problem, hovewer, the second Error with Color Theme Service had disappered somewhere on the way. Not sure when or where however.

Comment: I have the same issue.Did you find any resolution for it

Comment: No idea, I lost the project. But I realized, that I had problems with NuGet, which was causing my packages to crash. It was caused by Cordova tools, and after deinstalling them - painful process - everything started working again. Tomorrow morning I'll check that too.

Comment: @Milind Sorry, I still have the problem.